# Converting Older KVO to Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, key-value-observing

I'm trying to convert some old WWDC swift code to Swift 4.  I think that I have everything done, except for this last bit that does some KVO. This has been pretty difficult to narrow it down to this last bit because everything appears to function like the example code - but these KVO methods do not get called in Swift 4.  I found that out here: [Open Radar Bug](https://openradar.appspot.com/32700827)

What would be the Swift 4 way to represent the following?

// use the KVO mechanism to indicate that changes to "state" affect other properties as well

```
class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsReady() -> Set<NSObject> {
    return ["state" as NSObject]
}

class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsExecuting() -> Set<NSObject> {
    return ["state" as NSObject]
}

class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished() -> Set<NSObject> {
    return ["state" as NSObject]
}
```

And here are the variable definitions from the example:

```
    override var isReady: Bool {
    switch state {

        case .initialized:
            // If the operation has been cancelled, "isReady" should return true
            return isCancelled

        case .pending:
            // If the operation has been cancelled, "isReady" should return true
            guard !isCancelled else {
                return true
            }

            // If super isReady, conditions can be evaluated
            if super.isReady {
                evaluateConditions()
            }

            // Until conditions have been evaluated, "isReady" returns false
            return false

        case .ready:
            return super.isReady || isCancelled

        default:
            return false
    }
}

override var isExecuting: Bool {
    return state == .executing
}

override var isFinished: Bool {
    return state == .finished
}
```

If more code is needed, please let me know.

If this is a duplicate question, please link to the duplicate here.  I've been unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `keyPathsForValuesAffecting…` members can be properties instead of methods.
- They must be declared `@objc` because the KVO system accesses the properties using the Objective-C runtime.
- The properties should have type `Set<String>`.
- If you use the `#keyPath` directive, the compiler can tell you when you've used an invalid key path (for example because of a spelling error or a change to the property name).

Thus:

```
@objc class var keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsReady: Set<String> {
    return [#keyPath(state)]
}

@objc class var keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsExecuting: Set<String> {
    return [#keyPath(state)]
}

@objc class var keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished: Set<String> {
    return [#keyPath(state)]
}
```

You also need to make sure your `state` property is declared `@objc dynamic`.

Comment: I already had the properties declared as '''@objc dynamic''', so the last bit of the puzzle for me was adding the '''@objc''' to each of the class functions.  Thank you!

Comment: @user3096669 If your property is `dynamic`, don't use bare strings like this. Use `#keyPath` instead.

Comment: Where are the corresponding documentation from Apple about this? Please write down the link here.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that KVO is built using Objective-C, and it uses the Objective-C runtime to detect the existence of the `keyPathsForValuesAffecting` methods. In Swift 4, methods are no longer exposed to Objective-C by default if you don't include an `@objc` annotation on them. So, in a nutshell, adding the `@objc` annotation will probably fix your problem.

Another thing that I do—not strictly necessary, but it makes the code look a bit nicer—is to declare these as static constants. The `@objc` will cause these to get exposed to Objective-C as class methods, so it all works, and it's slightly cleaner. I like to put `private` on them, too, since these will never get called by Swift code, and there's no point cluttering your class's internal and/or public interface.

You also need to make sure that your `state` property is KVO-compliant, and sending the notifications when it is changed. You can either do this by making the property `dynamic`, which will cause the KVO system to automatically generate the notification calls for you, or you can manually call `willChangeValue(for:)` and `didChangeValue(for:)` (or the string-based versions, `willChangeValue(forKey:)` and `didChangeValue(forKey:)`) in your `willSet` and `didSet` handlers for the property.

Finally, don't use raw string key paths in Swift if you can avoid it. The `#keyPath()` mechanism is the preferred way to get string-based key paths (and for uses other than these legacy Objective-C methods that need to take strings, you should use the new `KeyPath` type which is better still). If your `state` property is not an Objective-C-compatible type, though, you're stuck with the old string key paths (in which case you'll fire the notifications in your `willSet` and `didSet` as described in the previous paragraph). Alternatively, you can create a dummy `Any`-typed object that mirrors your `state` property, purely for KVO purposes.

So, something like this:

```
@objc private static let keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsReady: Set<String> = [
    #keyPath(state)
]
```

Now, the `state` property. If it's an Objective-C-compatible type, it's easy:

```
@objc dynamic var state: ...
```

Or, if it's not:

```
@objc var state: SomeNonObjCThing {
    willSet { self.willChangeValue(forKey: "state") }
    didSet { self.didChangeValue(forKey: "state") }
}
```

OR:

```
@objc private var _stateKVO: Any { return self.state }
var state: SomeNonObjCThing {
    willSet { self.willChangeValue(for: \.stateKVO) }
    didSet { self.didChangeValue(for: \.stateKVO) }
}
// you can now use #keyPath(_stateKVO) in keyPathsForValuesAffecting...
```

Comment: Where are the corresponding documentation from Apple or elsewhere about this? For I can not find any related of KVO with Swift4+. Links or the like will be much appreciated.

Comment: Apple's documentation for KVO is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), but it's Objective-C based. Beyond that you mostly have to rely on understanding how the two languages interact and filling in the gaps (there is some Swift documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift) but it's quite poor). Part of the reason I wrote this long post was to help address that failing.

Answer (score 0):

`(NS)Operation` relies heavily on *NSObject-KVO*

The closest Swift syntax is

```
@objc private class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsReady() -> Set<String> {
    return [#keyPath(state)]
}

@objc private class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsExecuting() -> Set<String> {
    return [#keyPath(state)]
}

@objc private class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished() -> Set<String> {
    return [#keyPath(state)]
}
```

Side note: You might need to make `state` thread-safe.